# Помогите реализовать функцию через парсинг и сортировку

Tags: javascript, функции

Нужно реализовать функцию takeOldest(), которая принимает на вход список пользователей и возвращает самых взрослых. Количество возвращаемых пользователей задается вторым параметром, который по умолчанию равен единице.

Пример :

```
const users = [
    { name: 'Tirion', birthday: 'Nov 19, 1988' },
    { name: 'Sam', birthday: 'Nov 22, 1999' },
    { name: 'Rob', birthday: 'Jan 11, 1975' },
    { name: 'Sansa', birthday: 'Mar 20, 2001' },
    { name: 'Tisha', birthday: 'Feb 27, 1992' },
    { name: 'Chris', birthday: 'Dec 25, 1995' },
];
 
takeOldest(users);
// [
//   { name: 'Rob', birthday: 'Jan 11, 1975' },
// ];
```

Comment: Чем конкретно помочь?

Comment: Есть массив users с вложенными объектами
Функция takeOldest принимает на вход два аргумента(users,number)
При вызове функции второй аргумент по умолчанию равен единице
При вызове takeOldest(users),takeOldest(users,2),takeOldest(users,5),мы берём birthday users и преобразуем их в единое представлениe через Date.parse()
А потом их нужно отсортировать через _.sortBy

Comment: Я спросил чем конкретно помочь, а не "повторите ещё раз условие задачи"

Comment: @Mikhail_Penyukov Вам помог мой ответ?

Comment: @EmilYayv Почти)
Надо реализовать функцию через sortBy, обычный sort не принимает, но спасибо большое за наводку!
Щас постараюсь что нибудь придумать:)

Comment: @Mikhail_Penyukov А что у вас не принимает обычный sort?

Comment: @EmilYayv Всё принимает, просто сортировка шла от младших к старшим, а мне нужно наоборот
Но я уже всё сам изменил, там по мелочи, не обратил внимание на одну вещь:)
Опыт в задавание вопросов у меня отсутствует, поработаю ещё над этим
Спасибо Вам большое, что помогли!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делается очень просто:

```js
const users = [
    { name: 'Tirion', birthday: 'Nov 19, 1988' },
    { name: 'Sam', birthday: 'Nov 22, 1999' },
    { name: 'Rob', birthday: 'Jan 11, 1975' },
    { name: 'Sansa', birthday: 'Mar 20, 2001' },
    { name: 'Tisha', birthday: 'Feb 27, 1992' },
    { name: 'Chris', birthday: 'Dec 25, 1995' },
];
//Функция с обрезкой, по умолчанию 1
function takeOldest(users,num=1){
users.sort(function(a,b){
  // Turn your strings into dates, and then subtract them
  // to get a value that is either negative, positive, or zero.
  return new Date(b.birthday) - new Date(a.birthday);
});
return users.slice(0,num)
}
//Вызов функции
console.log(takeOldest(users))
```